# Why do my sprites have the same center coordinates (Android AndEngine)?

Tags: android, sprite, andengine, collision

I'm trying to figure out if my sprites have collided (they are circles, so I can't use collideswith()). For some reason, the coordinates of the centers return the same though centerB, which should be constant, always has the same coordinates as centerA. Any idea why?

```
    public boolean collision(){
    boolean collide=false;

    float radA, radB;
    float[] centerA;

    float[] centerB= yourSprite[spriteNum].getSceneCenterCoordinates();
    radB=yourSprite[spriteNum].getHeightScaled()/2;

    Log.e("SpriteNum",Integer.toString(spriteNum));
    if(spriteNum>0)
        for(int x=0;x<spriteNum;x++){
            centerA = yourSprite[x].getSceneCenterCoordinates();
            radA=yourSprite[x].getHeightScaled()/2;

            if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((centerA[0]-centerB[0]),2)+Math.pow((centerA[1]-centerB[1]),2))<(radA+radB))
                    collide=true;

            Log.e("CenterA",Float.toString(centerA[0])+", "+Float.toString(centerA[1]));
            Log.e("CenterB",Float.toString(centerB[0])+", "+Float.toString(centerB[1]));
            Log.e("RadA",Float.toString(radA));
            Log.e("RadB",Float.toString(radB));
        }
    return collide;
}
```

Here is where I create the sprites if it matters:

```
private void createSpriteOnTap(float x, float y) 
{
    scale = 1; 
    down = true;
    spriteNum++;
    yourSprite[spriteNum] = new Sprite(x, y, textureRegionForYourSprite, getVertexBufferObjectManager())
    {       
        boolean active = true;

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) 
        {
            down = true;
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove())
            {
                if(active){
                    setScale(scale += 0.05);
                    setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - getHeight() / 2);
                }
                if(collision()){
                    down=false;
                    active=false;
                }


            }
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
                down = false;
                active = false;

            }   
            Log.e("On Area touch",Boolean.toString(down));
            return true; 
        }

    };
    new Thread(new grow(yourSprite[spriteNum])).start();
    //lets register touch area
    yourScene.registerTouchArea(yourSprite[spriteNum]);
    //attach our sprite to the scene
    yourScene.attachChild(yourSprite[spriteNum]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the method description? It is shared, that means that when you call it the second time, you overwrite the previous values. That is why the coordinates are the same.

You will find the solution here:
http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/getting-the-center-coordinate-of-a-sprite-t8118-10.html